# Refer to website root in PHP (Windows)

Tags: php, windows, filesystems, xampp

I want to refer to my website root, or more exactly, to the directory above my script's one.

Let's say my website is example.com/test. I made a installation site which writes a config file. But it shouldn't write it to example.com/test/install/config.php, but to example.com/test/config.php. And the biggest pain in the **** is that I run on Windows (my development PC).

How do I do it?

Comment: can you provide a concrete example of what your tying to do, its a little unclear

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` doesn't care what platform it is on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the web-site document root, you can use:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

That should work regardless of the operating system and gives you a path on the local file system (so no www.etcetc.).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the fully-qualified path of your site root, from that file it is:

```
$root = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../..');
```

The double-dots work their way up the directory structure, then `realpath()` is used to turn it into a proper path. So if you want to traverse one less folder up, use two sets of dots rather than three.